# Groovy code in script block to replace general build step step()

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Among the possible steps one can use in a Jenkins pipeline, there is one with the name **step**, subtitled *General Build Step*. https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#step-general-build-step . I need to iterate on calling this step based on the contents of a file. I have created a groovy script to read the file and perform the iteration, but I am not sure how to create the equivalent of my step() in the groovy script. Here is the general format of the step I am trying to perform:

```
stage ('title') {
  steps {
    step([
       $class: 'UCDeployPublisher',
       siteName: 'literal string',
       deploy: [
          $class: 'com.urbancode.jenkins.plugins.ucdeploy.DeployHelper$DeployBlock',
          param1: 'another literal string',
          param2: 'yet another string'
       ]
    ])
  }
}
```

The script step I have developed looks like this:

```
steps {
  script {
     def content = readFile(file:'data.csv', encoding:'UTF-8');
     def lines = content.split('\n');
     for (line in lines) {
        // want to insert equivalent groovy code for the basic build step here
     }
  }
}
```

I'm expecting there is probably a trivial answer here. I'm just out of my element in the groovy/java world and I am not sure how to proceed. I have done extensive research, looked at source code for Jenkins, looked at plugins, etc. I am stuck!

Comment: Instead of creating what looks like an overloaded `step`, why not just define a global variable method and invoke that from the pipeline? https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#defining-global-variables

Comment: @MattSchuchard - thanks for the comment. I don't think I am following you. From your link, I see defining global variables in the scope of groovy and I see how you can create a method. But with that, I'm still not sure what to do with my step(). Are you suggesting that the global variable method contain the contents of my script {} step or something else. What will be the difference, in the end, if I use a global variable method which contains groovy code, vs. just putting the code in my script {} step?

Comment: The primary difference is what I recommended will be straightforward, readily supported, and simple to implement for your use case with the desired iteration extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following, simply move your `UCDeployPublisher` to a new function and call that from your loop.

```
steps {
  script {
     def content = readFile(file:'data.csv', encoding:'UTF-8');
     def lines = content.split('\n');
     for (line in lines) {
         runUCD(line)
     }
  }
}

// Groovy function 
def runUCD(def n) {
    stage ("title $n") {
      steps {
        step([
           $class: 'UCDeployPublisher',
           siteName: 'literal string',
           deploy: [
              $class: 'com.urbancode.jenkins.plugins.ucdeploy.DeployHelper$DeployBlock',
              param1: 'another literal string',
              param2: 'yet another string'
           ]
        ])
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey @ycr - thanks very much! This gave me the solution. It is elegant, simple and easy to understand. I like it a lot. 

I did have to tweak it a bit, as "steps" was not accepted in the groovy function, and I needed to position the groovy function outside my pipeline. So, the result structure is found in the next comment:

Comment: see my answer for the structure. Arg!

Answer (score 0):

This is showing the code related to my comment on the accepted answer

```
pipeline {
   stages {
      stage ('loop') {
         steps {
              script {
                  ... groovy to read/parse file and call runUCD
               }
         }
      }
   }
}
 
def runUCD(def param1, def param2) {
    stage ("title $param1") {
       step([
            ....
        ])
    }
}
```